# Horizontal ray with text label in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to draw a horizontal ray in pine script with a text label/title, just like a standard TradingView horizontal ray.

So far I have the following which gives me a horizontal ray but I cannot find a way to associate any text with it.

Any tips please?

```
first_point=chart.point.from_index(bar_index[1], 1)
second_point=chart.point.from_index(bar_index[0], 1)

line.new(first_point, second_point, extend=extend.right, color=color.orange, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `label.new()`. You probably want to set its `x` and `y` the same as your line and then write any text.

```
label.new(second_point, "Text")
```